# How increase the heap space to GATE?

Tags: windows-7, memory, java

How increase the heap space to [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/)? Windows version.

Comment: I found the GATE wiki after a few seconds of searching and this is covered by the FAQ: http://gate.ac.uk/wiki/gate-user-faq.html#section-2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> exe [normal arguments] -vmargs -Xmx[1]M [more VM args]

Where you replace exe with the executable you want to launch, and [1] with how many MB of memory you want it to have. Normal arguments you can probably leave out also.

Comment: Having just read the GATE WIKI, the app doesn't seem to work that way: "GATE doesn’t use the JAVA_OPTS variable. The default memory allocations are defined in the gate/build.xml file but you can override them by creating a file called build.properties in the same directory with these lines:"